# .on(click - make new image appear while incrementing score - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

Here's my  [jfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/JennyF/14auuyfm/) It doesn't look right when I run it. When I click Start in Firefox, the Timer starts to go down and the Mole appears. A new one appears every time I click start, just not when I click the Mole, and the Score isn't changing

I hope this isn't too broad, I don't know how to separate the question.

Whack-a-Mole Game for [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)/[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) class. I have to keep it so that the Mole appears when the Start Button is clicked and a new Mole appears every time you click on a Mole. The Score goes up one with every click.

The instructions say to use the `.on()` and to put it in the `.ready()` function. I'm supposed  to call my incrementing function in the process.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#start_button").click(function(){
            start();
            run();
        }); //end start button
        $("<img src='img/mole.png' />").on("click", function(){
            incScore();
            addMole();
        }); //end.on
    }); //end.ready
    function start(){
        $("#timer").show();
        addMole()
    }; //end start
```

Comment: Backtick is ` - the key to the left of 1. Makes it looks like `code`

Comment: ^ It's also the key that's directly under the [**`tilde`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) :)

Comment: Thank you! Why didn't they just call it the `tilde` key then?

Comment: Non Jquery Js is better for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `addMole` and `incScore` work I think you are pretty close.  Your img selector looks like it isn't quite right, ideally you should add a class to the mole image ("mole-img" for example) so you can make a selector like this `$('.mole-img').on('click', ...)`

If you want to call multiple functions you can supply an anonymous function to the click handler, that will get executed every time the mole is clicked. (just like the #start_button handler has)

I don't think you want to put the handler for the mole clicks inside of the #start_button handler, so I moved that outside.

The start function can also be inside of `$(document).ready`, you can define as many functions inside of that as you want.  Might want to put all your code inside.

If we put those things together it'll look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start_button").click(function(){
    start();
    run();
  });

  $('.mole-img').on('click', function(){
    addMole();
    incScore();
  });

  function start() {
    $("#timer").show();
    addMole();
  }
});
```

If you don't want to add a class to your img, `$("img[src='img/mole.png']").on...` might also work, but that seems more prone to break later.

Notes from fiddle:

Changed moleImg from an id to a class.  Not sure if you can have multiple moles active at the same time, ids should be unique so to be safe I am using class.

`setTimeout` takes a function not a string, you don't need parentheses after the function. `setTimeout("run()", 1000);` --> `setTimeout(run, 1000);`

Click handlers need to be written a little differnetly when they are supposed to trigger on things that will be added later on.  When the mole click handler is declared there are no moles on the screen.
Here is the way to write the handler to make it listen for elements that will be added later:

`$("container to look in").on("click", "element selector", function(){`

Apply that to the #gamespace and moleImg selector we get this:

`$("#gamespace").on("click", '.moleImg', function() {`

That should get you moving along, you might want to add `$("gamespace").empty()` to your addMole function so they don't keep piling up.

To get them to display randomly look into css `position: absolute`, `left`, `top` properties along with `Math.random`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I had it inside the `#start_button function` That brought the mole back to the screen, but it's not doing anything with the score. I'm not sure how to put a class on the image, it's just another function                                                          
    `function addMole(){        
   $("#gamespace").append("<img src='img/mole.png' />");
          }; //end mole`

Comment: `$("#gamespace").append("<img class='mole-img' src='img/mole.png' />");` will add moles with the `mole-img` class, I'm guessing your mole click listener isn't working currently

Comment: If you want to paste your program into https://jsfiddle.net/ and hit save up top then link it here we should be able to get it working

Comment: Okay, it's up there. The program didn't run right, though. When I click Start in Firefox, the Timer starts to go down and the Mole appears. A new one appears every time I click start, just not when I click the Mole, and the Score isn't changing.

Comment: Added comments from my changes to the fiddle.  Hope that helps you get started again, don't give up! One tip in general when things aren't working, using a lot of `console.log(myVariable)` and check for errors in the console (open it with ctrl+shfit+k in firefox)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's step 4. Now for step 5...and I have to go to bed. We aren't supposed to worry about some of those other things yet, next Project. Step 5 is to make the Mole appear every 2 seconds, still clickable with the score going up. That shouldn't be much different than the timer function.